# listing the gcp images in the marketplace from the gcloud commandline

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to list the gcp images in the marketplace from the gcloud commandline? "gcloud compute images list" only shows the standard images in the project and probably skips the marketplace listing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, the cli shows standard images only.

```
    --standard-images
      Show images from well-known image projects. The well known image
      projects are: centos-cloud, coreos-cloud, debian-cloud, cos-cloud,
      rhel-cloud, rhel-sap-cloud, suse-cloud, suse-sap-cloud,
      ubuntu-os-cloud, windows-cloud, windows-sql-cloud. Enabled by default,
      use --no-standard-images to disable.
```

To list images from specific project you want to specify `--project` flag.
Example:

```
# gcloud compute images list --project=click-to-deploy-images --filter="name ~ 'nginx.*'"
```

Comment: Hi Stan, Thanks. This is very useful. I am however unable to search for marketplace images. I guess what I need is to find out the project names of marketplace offerings perhaps?

Comment: @aanandan, marketplace images are just regular images stored across multi projects. So yes, you need to find out project name first and then perform a search. There is no way to search with gcloud cli from all public projects (similar how marketplace web page works) as far as I'm aware. I've double checked both APIs: v1 and beta. When ``--standard-images`` flag is specified the cli just performs search project by project, exactly the same behavior when ``--project`` specified. It's really annoying but for now seems like the web page is only way to find out a project related to images.

Comment: p.s. it would be cool to have something like ``# gcloud marketplace ...``

Comment: yup totally agree with you. Thanks for the follow up comments. Cheers.