# Is it possible to launch GCP marketplace entries using the gcloud CLI?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I've checked beta and alpha commands, and can't find any documentation.  I'm assuming the answer is no, but thought someone might know.

Google has well documented on their site how to launch marketplace entries interactively with a browser, but I'm interested in if it's possible to do it non-interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such thing, to make sure you can use

```
gcloud help -- marketplace
```

to get a list of all gcloud commands with the expression 'marketplace' including alphas and betas.

As an alternative, you can use [Deploment Manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/) for automation

Answer (score 2):

Straight answer is NO.

However, If you are looking to accomplish installing it from API you may be able to get the details of the image you're interested in provided you know the project.

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51592502/listing-the-gcp-images-in-the-marketplace-from-the-gcloud-commandline)

You can describe the image to get the details necessary to install it on a compute engine. Ignore, if this is not something you're trying to accomplish.